# Does the first statement imply the second?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

(a) The number $\sqrt{2}$ is either rational or irrational. If $\sqrt{2}$ rational then $\sqrt{(2)}^2$ is rational too. Either $\sqrt{2}$, or $\sqrt{(2)}^2$ is not rational.

(b) Consequently $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

I get this statement and I should show that this is true or false. I think I should formalize it somehow, but I still don't know how it works. But I think that the first statement doesn't imply the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, there are two ways we can take the either…or.

If we take it as exclusive (i.e. meaning *exactly one of these two numbers is not rational*), then (b) follows from (a). Indeed, suppose (b) didn't hold. Then $\sqrt2$ would be rational. But then $\sqrt{2}^2$ would also be, so $\sqrt2,\sqrt2^2$ would both be rational, contradicting the last part of (a).

If we take it as non-exclusive (i.e. meaning *at least one of these two numbers is not rational*), then (b) still follow, by the same argument.

The third part of (a) is pretty strange, because how should one know that at least one (or exactly one) of two numbers is not rational? Sounds like some logic puzzle.

**My formal interpretation of the problem**

Say $R(x)$ indicates "$x$ is rational". Then (a) is $(R(\sqrt2)\veebar\lnot R(\sqrt2))\land(R(\sqrt2)\vdash R(2))\land(\lnot R(\sqrt2)\vee\lnot R(2))$, and (b) is $\lnot R(\sqrt2)$, and you must prove $(a)\vdash(b)$.

To do this, try adding $R(\sqrt2)$ to (a). Now you are starting from $(R(\sqrt2)\veebar\lnot R(\sqrt2))\land(R(\sqrt2)\vdash R(2))\land(\lnot R(\sqrt2)\vee\lnot R(2))\land R(\sqrt2)$. Clearly, $(\lnot R(\sqrt2)\vee\lnot R(2))\land R(\sqrt2)\vdash\lnot R(2)$, but then you have $R(\sqrt2)\land(R(\sqrt2)\vdash R(2))\land(\not R(2))$, which implies $R(2)\land(\not R(2))$, a contradiction.

The interpretation ambiguity is as to whether the last part of (a) should have a $\vee$ or a $\veebar$, but even if it were $\lnot R(\sqrt2)\veebar\lnot R(2)$, the proof above would work just as well.

Try giving this to your teacher and seeing what he says. And excuse any logic symbol errors, since I never formalized logic this way.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers I have to ask tomorrow my teacher, what does this exactly mean.

Comment: @Zauberkerl Yes, that would be best thing to do. I doubt it's anything complicated, I guess it's just some sort of ambiguous or badly formulated statement.

Comment: @peter.petrov, I'll send tomorrow an answer what he said about it.

Comment: I asked today my teacher about this problem,  he said that I have to solve this example with using Predicate logic. As he said I have to formalize first of all this problem. As I tried:

Comment: I asked today my teacher about this problem,  he said that I have to solve this example with using Predicate logic. As he said I have to formalize first of all this problem. As I tried:$R(x)$ is rational $(x\cdot x=2)\implies(R(x)\cup\neg R(x))$

$(x\cdot x)=2 \implies R(x) \cup (x\cdot x=2)\implies \neg R(x\cdot x)$

Comment: I suggest you delete the comment duplicating the first part of this one, since it is just a partial duplicate.

Comment: And see the edit with my formalization @Zauberkerl.

Comment: @MickG, thank you for your work I'll work today on this problem if I get a new solution I'll share it with you

Comment: What do you exactly mean under $\veebar$?

Comment: $A\lor B$ means $A$ or $B$ or both, $A\veebar B$ means $A$ or $B$ but not both.

Answer (score 2):

If by first statement you mean (a), then you're correct: no, (a) does not imply (b).
Actually that last part of (a) saying "either $\sqrt{2}$, or $\sqrt{(2)}^2$ is not rational"
makes no sense (doesn't follow from anything said so far).
The first two parts of (a) are true (but they are true for any real number, not just for $\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: I also think so, that the last part of (a) makes no sense, but I'm a little bit confused why does the text of the example contain it.

Comment: and how can I show that formally that the first (a) part doesn't implify the second part(b)?

Comment: @Zauberkerl I would post the whole example. Maybe then we'll find some sense in it. But as you've put it here, that's all we can say.

Comment: @Zauberkerl First of all: how can we prove the last part of (a). What sense does it make? Where does it come from? I would only then worry if (a) => (b) or not.

Comment: But unfortunately the example is in an other language and I tried to translate it into English, but in this case it's a little bit confusing.

Comment: I think that from the second part of (a) is missing the word of irrational.